# In Ruby on Rails, what kind of design pattern is to use false to denote don't do DB look up and nil to denote ok to look up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, restful-authentication, code-readability

In [Restful Authentication](https://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication), I found that `current_user` is quite intricate that, when `@current_user` is set to false, then it means don't try to find user again (usually from DB), while `nil` means that's ok, can look up again in DB:

Line 8 of `lib/authenticated_system.rb`

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= (login_from_session 
                      || login_from_basic_auth 
                      || login_from_cookie) unless @current_user == false
end
```

the intricate thing is, if it tries to look up the DB from `login_from_session`, etc, and can't find it, then the final value that gets assigned to `@current_user` is `nil`, and the method returns `nil` (which is the last evaluated value in the method).  Unless there are two other places in the code elsewhere that actually can set `@current_user` to false, and that will trigger the `unless`, causing the whole statement to return `nil`, while `@current_user` remains as `false`, and the method returns `nil`...

I was almost speechless for the code to rely on these intricate facts.  `false` has special meaning, and `nil` has special meaning in the code, but is not documented, not commented, and `current_user` can be `nil`, while `@current_user` can continue to be `false`.  Is it actually a design pattern, so people are familiar with it and know it well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestfulAuthentication is considered quite old and nasty at this point in Rails history, partly because of code like what you are pointing out.

I think most people would advise you to go with a more modern authentication solution such as Devise or Authlogic.

Comment: Authlogic is kinda abandoned by the developer (Ben Johnson) behind it. Moreover, it barely works on Rails 3.